# Disable EntityFrameWork Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am working with Database that already exists and any updates to the database is controlled by DB Team.

Is there a way that I  don't use migrations and disable it entirely since the Database updates will happen out of Band from the WebAP project

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Database.SetInitializer()` as `null` as shown below.

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
   public MyDbContext() : base("MyConnName")
    {
       Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);//disable initializer
    }
}
```